# How to stop Terminal from using special characters?

Tags: terminal, macos, internationalization, unicode

When I'm using arguments with quotes in the Terminal, the quote is first highlighted and then changes to a special character when certain characters are entered after it.

For example trying to type `"u` changes to `ü`.

How do I disable this?

I'm on OS X El Capitan, 10.11.6

Comment: Could you give a more complete example of this? I'm in Terminal and I can type a double-quote, then a lowercase u, and the umlaut does not appear.

Comment: Well I can't really explain it any further. I must have changed a system setting somewhere that enables it but I have no idea how to change it back (I'm not a mac guy).

Comment: Hi Jimmi, welcome to Ask Different. Which keyboard is configured on your Mac? (You can find this information in Apple menu>System Preferences>Keyboard>Input Sources)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to system prefs/keyboard/input sources and get rid of the layout called US International PC.  Use US or ABC instead.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using iTerm2, then select `Esc+` for the Left Option Key in Preferences > Profile > Keys. Then you can use `Option-b` for the previous word and `Option-f` for the next word.

[image]

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to have anything at all to do with the question.  Did you intend to post it somewhere else?